# Android Studio - Reducing Animation Resources

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-resources, animationdrawable

I have created a 20-frame animation using Adobe and plan to make a screensaver for my app. It is a security app on a tablet I provide to the customer, so it is always plugged in, with only my app running. Even so, the tablets aren't the greatest.

Due to the fact that I will be running this animation all day, until a security issue brings us out of the animation, I want to be sure I do this correctly the first time. I am worried about resources used (cpu and memory).

I have compressed each .png image, then in Android Studio, converted each image to the webp format.

- 20 images added to drawable folder
- animation.xml file created, each frame set to 60ms duration.
- Using AnimationDrawable object
- Overriding onWindowFocusChanged() so I can start the animation after the window is loaded.

Is there anything further I can do to reduce the impact on the hardware resources? I'd prefer to NOT use any third party libraries, but am open to trying some if it seems helpful.

EDIT: Each image, after compression, is close to 140KB (About 2800KB altogether).

EDIT AGAIN: Just wanted to point out that i'm only using a single screen density, so adjusting images for ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xdpi, won't make a difference in this particular case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Vectors are all the rage these days...

Comment: I agree, but I don't see how that is related to this post lol. I can't recreate a 3D object made in Adobe After Effects with vectors.